# How to check owner of cNFT given asset id?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, compression, cnft

I am trying to write a function in Anchor (Rust) where I need to check that the owner of the cNFT asset id matches the signer id. I have been looking at the mpl-bubblegum documentation but didn't find anything. Does anyone know if it's possible, and if so how?
Thank you for the help